# Why don't the Shand die out?

Tags: terry-pratchett, strata

Shand are a fictional race from Terry Prattchet's *Strata*, who survive only on other Shand. In fact without the certain proteins in a Shand's diet they go into a homicidal feeding rage.

Currently they have the Dumb Waiter that can survive on artificial protein, but prior to this, how did they survive?

Comment: I haven't read the book, but how many Shand does one Shand need to eat in its lifetime in order to get enough protein?  As long as the answer is "less than one", they wouldn't necessarily die out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I read it, shandi can eat (and get sustenance from) protein from other animal species from their planet. What I do find is this:

> It had two tusks, said to have been used originally for scraping molluscs from the beds of freezing oceans, now as useless as the vermiform appendix, and carved into status-denoting shapes.

and this:

> The plain truth was that the shandi liked eating shand. Can you fit ritual cannibalism into a civilization? They did. (…) ‘What we did out of need we do for … sport, I think it would be called (…)’.

My impression is that while shandi have evolved to have a more and more selective diet, they can still survive, albeit sometimes barely, on their home planet. What they can't do is take a whole ecosystem into space, so they cannot leave their planet without a dumbwaiter to produce artificial food.

Answer (score 0):

An entirely speculative answer, but perhaps they work in a similar way to the Regul in C. J. Cherryh's ["Faded Sun"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faded_Sun_Trilogy) trilogy.  They may have an immature stage which can eat things other than Shand, which is bred in large numbers as a food source.  The few that reach maturity then metamorphose into the adult form which can only eat other (mature or immature) Shand.

Comment: "entirely speculative answer"